# How to find minimal and maximal address of dll

Tags: c, memory, dll

I scan a process memory by injecting dll and read it's memory.
The problem is that I also reads the memory of the dll. Does someone know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GetModuleInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation?redirectedfrom=MSDN), which can accept both an `HPROCESS` for your remote process and a `HMODULE` for your injected DLL, and which returns the following information in a [`MODULEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-moduleinfo) struct:

```
typedef struct _MODULEINFO {
  LPVOID lpBaseOfDll;
  DWORD  SizeOfImage;
  LPVOID EntryPoint;
} MODULEINFO, *LPMODULEINFO;
```

So you can know the start address of your injected DLL via the `lpBaseOfDll` field and the end address via `lpBaseOfDll + SizeOfImage`.

---

This can also work for a DLL in your current process using `GetCurrentProcess`  and e.g. `GetModuleHandle`.

Comment: But will it return the start address of the injected process or the dll?

Comment: It'll return the start address of the DLL

Comment: It works on the global parameters, I need it to work on the local parameters.

Comment: @GUYYankovitch Local parameters are on the stack, which is outside of the DLL's address space. It's trickier to do this - one way is to write code in your `DLLMain` which registers the address of a local variable - and infers stack information. There is also the [GetCurrentThreadStackLimits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadstacklimits) API but a) it's not available in early versions of Windows and b) it'll return the stack of a single thread, which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: Indeed, note that if your DLL has multiple threads - it'll have multiple stacks.

Comment: Ok i understand.
what about PEB_LDR_DATA?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235372/discussion-between-guy-yankovitch-and-daniel-kleinstein).